# Client unauthorized error when trying to use Twitter API v2 in Postman

Tags: api, authentication, authorization, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to use **Twitter API version 2** in **Postman**, but I keep getting a "`client unauthorized`" error. I have followed the documentation and created a project(inside of which is my app) on the Twitter Developer portal, and I am using the correct API key and secret.

I have also read that for **free** apps, we can only use the **user lookup** endpoint and the post, delete, or create tweet endpoints. However, even when I try to use the user lookup endpoint, I still get the same error.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? How can I troubleshoot this issue and successfully use the Twitter API v2 in Postman? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
{
    "client_id": "27053233",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, and based on what I've read, the user lookup endpoint that is available for free users is "GET /2/users/me", which is probably not the one that you are trying to use.

Sources:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/free
https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/issues/58#issuecomment-1533659996